# Align span text with .btn

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with the `.card` below and having the dickens of a time getting the text "You liked this." in-line with the Like and Comment `.btn-links` beneath the `hr` element.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card mx-auto mt-5" style="width:500px">
    <div class="card-body">
      <hr>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-link">Like</button>
        <span class="text-muted" style="">You liked this.</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right">3  Comments</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried everything I can think of. Changing the display property. Using margins or padding. Adjusting the font-height. None of it has worked. I'm not sure how to get it to align and any help would be appreciated.

I probably could get it to work with using floats or even flexbox, but that seems over kill and I'd prefer not to if possible. Thanks.

Comment: try the class `align-middle` to the span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the vertical alignment, use the bootstrap class `align-middle` on your span.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card mx-auto mt-5" style="width:500px">
    <div class="card-body">
      <hr>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-link">Like</button>
        <span class="text-muted align-middle">You liked this.</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right">3  Comments</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, totally missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .btn-link {
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #007bff;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: -4px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="card mx-auto mt-5" style="width:500px">
        <div class="card-body">
            <hr>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-link">Like</button>
                <span class="text-muted" style="">You liked this.</span>
                <button class="btn btn-link float-right">3  Comments</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```